# Auto start an "add to homepage" link on desktop

Tags: applications

Is there a way to have a link created via Chrome's "add to homepage" auto start on bootup?

I've tried apps that allow you to set this up, but they don't work because the link I am trying to open is not recognized as an app.

Comment: Probably through Tasker and Autoinput, give me some time.